# Configuring TomEE internal ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, java-ee-7, apache-tomee

I'm trying to use the **TomEE internal ActiveMQ**, but this error crashes:

```
Failed to build body from content. Serializable class not available to broker. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class ru.path.dto! This class is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

I changed the TomEE settings, but it didn't help:

```
tomee.serialization.class.blacklist = -
tomee.serialization.class.whitelist =
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message for the failure states (in part):

```
Please take a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more information on how to configure trusted classes.
```

[The cited documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html) indicates that the `org.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES` system property should be set. I see no evidence that you're actually setting this system property.

The settings you're using are for the [Ejbd Transport](https://tomee.apache.org/ejbd-transport.html). This is not valid for the embedded instance of ActiveMQ.

Try this instead:

```
-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=ru.path.dto
```

Comment: Thanks, but for standalone ActiveMQ everything is clear, but for internal ActiveMQ, I still did not understand which configuration file to write to. That's why I was making changes to the tomee configuration file.

Comment: A system property is a system property whether ActiveMQ is running standalone or embedded (e.g. in TomEE). You just need to set the system property when you start the JVM.

Comment: figured it out, thanks!